# Is there any way I can randomize the display of input submitted?

Tags: javascript, html, css, random, input

I'm not super great a javascript yet and I'm mostly a front end person. I am trying to have people's submissions be randomized across the screen but not entirely sure how to (it's okay if it wipes away everything with the refresh of the page). I have this so far:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
    }
</script>
```

Which gives me an option where someone submits something and it appears on the bottom but I'm trying to have each response randomize somewhere on the screen.

I have the input displayed beneath the textbox but can't figure out how to have multiple answers show and then randomize across the screen.

Comment: Hey, welcome to stackoverflow! Could you please provide the full code (not just this function) and some context? where's the data coming from? user input? a back-end? are you looking to just scatter "text boxes" around the screen randomly?

Answer (score 0):

Create multiple elements where you display the responses, then select one of them randomly when you're displaying.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
  let divs = document.querySelectorAll(".demo");
  let chosen = divs[Math.floor(Math.random() * divs.length)];
  chosen.innerText = x;
}
```

```css
.demo {
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<input id="myText"> <button onclick="myFunction()">Enter</button>
<div class="demo"></div>
<div class="demo"></div>
<div class="demo"></div>
<div class="demo"></div>
<div class="demo"></div>
<div class="demo"></div>
<div class="demo"></div>
```